# Angular Nested Form Component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying studying more about Angular, specifically having re-usable components as Form.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4rggse?file=src/app/sec/sec.component.ts

In this example I have the `SecComponent` that's a form that can be re-used elsewhere in the application. My problem is that when I click on the submit button, it doesn't log the value of date. (Which in this example is just a simple string). What am I missing?

Thank you for the help

Comment: The form you bound your `FormGroup` to in `app.component.html` has no definition for a `FormControl` named 'date'. You should pass the `app.component.ts`'s `FormGroup` as an `Input` variable to the `sec.component.ts` and use the passed in `FormGroup` in the `sec.component.html`.

Comment: I edited your StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yznuxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

there're two ways to achieve the same result

1. Create a custom form control that implements controlValueAccesor
2. Create a component and pass the FormControl (or the Form and a
   field)

when you use a custom form control that implements controlValueAccesor the "key" is this function

```
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCb = fn;
  }
```

So, when we change "something" we need call to the function this.onChangeCb(). The stackblitz that you show use a "setter" in the way that if you use

```
this.value="what ever"
```

You call the function and propagate the change. You can get it if you use not a FormGroup else a simple [ngModel]. That's if your sec.html is simply

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" placeholder="Date" />
```

Other way can be in a ngOnInit write some like

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.f.get('date').valueChange.subscribe(res=>{
   this.value=res;
  })
}
```

The second approach is the MrRobot's answer -but then you can remove all about the controlValueAccesor-. You pass in an input the formGroup or the formControl. Really if only pass the form, you need that the formControlName was the same in the child tan in the parent. Generally you can pass simple the formControl

```
control:FormControl
@Input('control') set _(value){
   this.control =value as FormControl

<input [formControl="control">
```

And you use as

```
<app-sec [control]="f.get('date')"></app-sec>
```